# How to round up to nearst decimals? E.g. 23.33 to final output to 23.5 and 23.55 to final output to 24

Tags: sql

How to round up to nearst decimals? E.g. 23.33 to final output to 23.5 and 23.55 to final output to 24

Comment: Spend a few more minutes on formulating the question.  I don't see how your examples could be arrived at by a single rule.  But maybe that's because you haven't told us enough.  Traditional "school" rounding to one decimal place would normally round down 23.33 to 23.3 (not 23.4 or 23.5), 23.5 rounded to the nearest whole number would give 24.

Answer (score -1):

Use `ceil()` function to "round up to closest 0.5".

```
ceil(col * 2) / 2
```

The above will return -1 for -1.3. If you instead want -1.5, do

```
sign(col) * CEIL(ABS(col) * 2) / 2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/L3bKT-V7